# How do I remove elementary OS and put Windows back on?

Tags: release-freya, software-installation, microsoft-windows

I don't want elementary OS on my computer anymore and just want Windows on it. How do I remove elementary OS and wipe the hard drive to put Windows back on via a USB?

Comment: Are you dual booting

Comment: What is wrong with elementary OS.We need to know why users are leaving .Then I can tell the development team to fix it

Comment: Your question has already been answered [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/758463/how-do-i-wipe-a-harddrive-with-ubuntu-on-it) and [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1067280/if-i-install-windows-from-from-usb-will-ubuntu-be-removed-from-my-harddrive-com)

Comment: Question sponsored by Windows™

Comment: This question will become very popular since I think there are a lot of elementary OS users that don't want to learn how to use so they go back to M$ Windows. I am a user of elementary OS. I rarely use my Windows 10 dual boot

Comment: This question already has 22 views while questions posted before have only about 10 views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using OS Uninstaller if Windows is installed (dual boot).This will remove elementary OS from you hard drive.A tutorial can be found on the Ubuntu Wiki at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller.

If you only have elementary OS installed , just delete all the partitions when you install Windows.

Both of these will delete all data on your elementary OS partition.

Comment: How do I delete partitions when I install Windows? And, nothings wrong. I still have Elementary OS on my old computer, this just my work computer, so I am switching....

Comment: When installing and it asks you which partition to install to delete all partition and create a new one for Windows

Comment: Were you having problems running Windows software on Linux. Then you can use WINE (Wine is not a emulator) which is a Windows compatibility layer for Linux

Comment: So will it give me the option to delete all partitions or pick which partition to install?

Comment: It will give you a partition tool that lets you do anything with partitions

Answer (score 0):

Put in a Windows USB, wipe all partitions and just install Windows.